# Facelets tag for hidden input?

Tags: jsf, input, tags, hidden

There is a Facelets tag for `<input type="text">`:

```
<h:inputText />
```

Is there a Facelets tag for `<input type="hidden">`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [`<h:inputHidden>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputHidden.html) (please bookmark the [tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/), it shows all available tags).

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{bean.input}" />
```

Depending on the concrete functional requirement, this may be not what you're looking for. This does for example not allow you to add an extra request parameter or something. For that you should be using `<f:param>` in the command component instead. Or if you just want to retain a bean property in the subsequent POST request, rather put the bean in the view scope instead.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for, but I want to put a value into the bean.input, can I do this?